# Other SecurityManager implementations available?

Tags: java, securitymanager

Is there any other implementation (e.g. in an OSS project) of a **Java SecurityManager** available which has more features than the one in the JDK?

I'm looking for features like

- configurable at runtime
- policies updateable at runtime, read from other data sources than a `security.policy` file
- Thread-aware, e.g. different policies per Thread
- Higher-level policies, e.g. "Disable network functions, but allow JDBC traffic"
- Common predefined policies, e.g. "Allow read-access to usual system properties like `file.encoding` or `line.separator`, but disallow read-access to user.home"
- Monitoring and audit trace logging, e.g. "Log all file access, log all network access going NOT to knownhost.example.org"
- Blocking jobs "requesting" a permission until an administrator grants permission, letting the thread/job continue
- ...

I'm pretty sure that application servers (at least the commercial ones) have their own `SecurityManager` implementation or at least their own policy configuration. I'm wondering if there is any free project with similar requirements.

Comment: No, I didn't really find a suitable library which offers a sophisticated implementation of a SecurityManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Dynamic [`ProtectionDomain`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html) (introduced in 1.4 IIRC), delegate to the modifiable `Policy`.
- Determining permissions by thread is, erm, tricky. The applet security managaer does it by `ThreadGroup`, which is generally considered a bad thing.
- You can allow connections to specific ports. Similarly you can have a privileged JDBC driver that perhaps proxies onto another driver asserting particular privileges through `AccessController.doPrivileged`.
- Permissions for system properties can be specified for each individual key.
- `AccessController` in the Sun/Oracle implementation does have tracing features.
- Applets/WebStart will show a dialog on, for instance, printing. But the JNLP services approach is much better.

"Glossitope" attempted to have a system that sprung up a dialog box every time a permission was requested. Of course, the request makes no sense to the user that just wants to see the dancing pigs. (Glossitope was an attempt at a Java version of the Vista side panel thing. The features added to 6u10 (drag-and-drop install, non-rectangular windows, warning icon instead of banner, JNLP services) make it mostly redundant.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a standalone SecurityManager project. Any application server (JBoss, Glassfish) will contain one to control what a loaded application can do.

Here are some links I found on the subject of rolling your own:

- [Writing a Security Manager](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed2.html)
- [Java2s SecurityManager examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/0800__SecurityManager.htm)
- [Java World: Java Tip 20](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip20.html) - a bit old, but a interesting (ab)use of a SM